# Let QTabWidget switch to corresponding page when mouse cursor hover on the tab

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I want to show the corresponding page when mouse cursor hover on the tab of a `QTabWidget`.
[image: here]

For example, when the mouse cursor hover on tab ‘page2’ here , I hope the `QTabWidget` shows the corresponding page automatically instead of clicking. How to implement this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try adding an event filter on the QTabWidget object's QTabBar in order to trap the mouse move event. In the filter handler, use QTabBar::tabAt( QPoint ) to find which tab is below the cursor. Set up a timer when the cursor first enters a given tab, reset time when cursor leaves it. When the timer fires, switch active tabs.

Comment: thanks ,I implementation more or less like your way ,here is make code http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30206/

Answer (score 0):

You may try using setTabToolTop function.

```
ui->tabWidgetHz->setTabToolTip(0,"tooltip for tab1.");
ui->tabWidgetHz->setTabToolTip(1,"tooltip for tab2.");
ui->tabWidgetHz->setTabToolTip(2,"tooltip for tab3");
```